# should I reuse gwt instances (registry objects, loaders) or obtain fresh copy every time?

Tags: gwt

I'm newbie in gwt so sorry for this simple question.

I can call `Registry.get("id")` every time or I can cache returned value in field, what is better (how fast/slow `Registry.get("id")` is?)

Similar question for `RpcProxy` instance and different `loader` instances.

Comment: What is `Registry`? do you mean `RootPanel`? `RootPanel`s are cached, but the cache is _validated_ each time. Otherwise, most `GWT.create()`d objects are cheap to create because they actually generate mostly static implementations, so the instance is optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: Where do you find little gems like "the cache is validated each time"?

Comment: @Andrei: Seriously, that is great stuff.  Is it documented somewhere or is Thomas a Google GWT developer?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a good question. You should always try to reuse your instances instead of creating new ones, especially with GWT client Java code which becomes Javascript at runtime. The overhead of instantiating objects in JS (even with all the optimisations you get from GWT) can become quickly unwieldy if you're not carefull. Try it for yourself, have a list of 200 gwt Labels of which you only display 10 at a time versus instantiating only 10 and reusing them each time the values change, you'll see the difference in the time your browser takes to render.

Comment: The cost is not with JS objects but with DOM elements (and otherwise manipulating the document). So, widgets have a high instantiation cost and should be "recycled", but everything else is cheap.

Comment: I agree with Thomas. Also, I wouldn't recommend to "always reuse your instances" - it's often a lot better to create new instances, because that can lead to much better readability/traceability of your code (especially when you can make objects immutable), shorter code (construction code only), much easier refactoring, and probably fewer bugs.

Comment: so I should try to reuse my instances, but if this affects readability, it's ok to instatiate new one? Note to instantiate new `loader` I need to instatiate many things - rpcproxy etc.

Comment: Well as the guys who commented on my answer say, you should mainly focus on DOM altering objects (basically the GWT Widget descendants) when reusing instances, as those are the most heavyweight. For others you should balance it out between code readability and number of instances.

Comment: If you are going to reuse, you might want to look at the Supplier interface and Suppliers class in Guava.  These are GWT-compatible and provide useful static methods for memoizing a class.